# I can't get my navigation bar buttons to show the background buttons. How do I solve this?

Tags: html, css

Here are my CSS and HTML codes respectively :

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #55AAFF;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #1D72C7;
}

.indextext
{
    font-family: roboto, arial, calibri, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 150px 0px 150px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Welcome - Bookmark Designs - Web Design Solutions</title>
  <link href="C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\New folder\homepage_css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="logoimg">
  <img src="" </img>
  </div>
  <div class="nav"
  <ul>
   <li id=1><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li id=2><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li id=3><a href="">Prices</a></li>
   <li id=4><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li id=5><a href="">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div> 
  <div class="mainimg">
  <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="indextext">
  <p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
  </div>
```

I've provided a link to the output below. Also, how do I stop those bullet points from appearing?

I've tried long and hard and racked my limited knowledge to what may be causing this and did a lot of trial and error but most things I tried kept worsening things.

Thank you very much.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g7ajz7wn/) what you want?

Comment: You've got some HTML problems. Your image tag is not properly closed (and it doesn't need a separate </img> closing tag), and your <div class="nav" isn't closed. That's probably causing your CSS errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="logoimg">
    <img src="">
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id=1><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id=2><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id=3><a href="">Prices</a></li>
        <li id=4><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li id=5><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<div class="mainimg">
    <img src="">
</div>
<div class="indextext">
  <p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
</div>
```

- `img` tags don't have closing `</img>`
- You were missing a closing `>` on a `div`
- Put your `id` attribute values inside quotes

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zhtq9jn9/1/